# Issue with feed_dict Shape of the Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a Linear Regression Model for multiple variables using [this](https://github.com/sentimos/linear-regression/blob/master/Linear%20Regression.ipynb) tutorial. I tried to replace that with my own data set using the `train_test_split()` method of sklearn.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('airfoil_self_noise.csv',sep=',')
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_true, X_test, y_true, y_test = train_test_split(df.iloc[:,:-1].values,df.iloc[:,-1].values,test_size = 0.2, random_state=0)

n_features = np.shape(X_true)[1]
m_examples = np.shape(X_true)[0]

# Placeholder that is fed input data.
X_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_features], "X_in")

# The model: we assume y = X_in * w + b
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_features, 1)), name="w")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[]), name="b")
h = tf.add(tf.matmul(X_in, w), b, name="h")

# Placeholder that is fed observed results.
y_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,None], "y_in")

# The loss function: we are minimizing square root of mean 
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_in, h)), name="loss")
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(loss_op)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(1000):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={
          X_in: X_true, 
          y_in: y_true
        })
    w_computed = sess.run(w)
    b_computed = sess.run(b)


print ("w computed [%s]" % ', '.join(['%.5f' % x for x in w_computed.flatten()]))
print ("w actual   [%s]" % ', '.join(['%.5f' % x for x in w_true.flatten()]))
print ("b computed %.3f" % b_computed)
print ("b actual  %.3f" % b_true[0])
```

The problem I seem to have is with the shape of the numpy array fed to y_in.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Airfoil_Test_TF.py", line 32, in <module>
    y_in: y_true
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1128, in _run
    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1202,) for Tensor 'y_in:0', which has shape '(1, ?)'
```

I have tried to modify the dimensions of the placeholder for y_in, but it doesn't do anything. The tutorial originally has defined the placeholder with the dimensions `[None,1]` instead of this way, but I can't find a way to transpose `y_true` to the shape (,1202) because a single dimensional array can't be transposed in numpy.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call

```
y_true = y_true.reshape((1,-1))
```

This should do the trick.

**Short explanation**:

In numpy the shape `(10,)` is just a one dimensional vector.
The shape `(10, 1)` represents an explicit row vector.
The shape `(1, 10)` represents a column vector.